# Spring data elasticsearch sorting

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to learn spring data elasticsearch, and created a sample project. Right now, I am trying to get familiar with the mechanics of sorting.

Simply put, I have a Person class, that has a firstName and lastName field. I am trying to sort on the lastNameField.

Here is my Person class:

```
@Document(indexName = "entities", type = "person", shards=1, replicas=0)
public class Person {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field(type=FieldType.String, index=FieldIndex.not_analyzed)
    private String firstName;
    @Field(type=FieldType.String, index=FieldIndex.not_analyzed)
    private String lastName;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

Here is my DAO logic:

```
@Override
public Page<Person> getPeople(int pageNumber, int pageSize, Direction direction, String...sortFields) {
    return personRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(pageNumber, pageSize, direction, sortFields));
}
```

The personRepository is an empty interface that extends PagingAndSortingRepository

And the actual call:

```
int pageSize = 1;
int currentPageNumber = -1;
boolean morePages = true;
while(morePages){
    Page<Person> results = personDataHandler.getPeople(currentPageNumber+1, pageSize, Direction.DESC, "firstName");
    List<Person> people = results.getContent();
    if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(people)){
        for(Person currentPerson: people){
            System.out.println("[firstName: "+currentPerson.getFirstName()+", lastName: "+currentPerson.getLastName()+"]");
        }
    }
    currentPageNumber++;
    morePages = results.hasNext();
}
```

Could having a page size of 1 be the issue?

Comment: Your code seems to be correct unless I missing something. Where exactly are you stuck ?

Comment: The search is running, but the results just aren't being sorted

Comment: Any chance firstName has more than one word ? Also, can you share the mapping for the type. Besides, do check if its getting sorted using raw ES query.